# How in SPSS to create week name variable as string equal to first day of the week (like Sunday's date)

Tags: python, datetime, spss

Let's say I have a date variable called "date".
I need to get a "week"  variable that shows not the week number, but week name, that is, actually, first day of the week. For example,
current week value would be '2019-Jul-28' and I need this value across the whole week. And the next week would read '2019-08-04' and so on going backward and forward.

The solution I have uses python, but I get a warning message in SPSS and don't get any new variable values:

```
STRING day (A10).
STRING monthday monthnumber (A2).  
DO IF (XDATE.MDAY(date) < 10).
COMPUTE monthday = 
CONCAT('0',STRING(XDATE.MDAY(date),F1)).
ELSE.
COMPUTE monthday = 
STRING(XDATE.MDAY(date),F2).
END IF.
EXECUTE.

DO IF (XDATE.MONTH(date) < 10).
COMPUTE monthnumber = 
CONCAT('0',STRING(XDATE.MONTH(date),F1)).
ELSE.
COMPUTE monthnumber = 
STRING(XDATE.MONTH(date),F2).
END IF.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE day =  
CONCAT(monthday,'/',monthnumber,'/',STRING(XDATE.YEAR(date),F4)).
        EXECUTE.

STRING Week (A11).

begin program. 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def weekname(day):
    dt = datetime.strptime(day, '%d/%m/%Y')
    week = dt - timedelta(days=dt.weekday())
    return week.strftime('%Y/%b/%d')
end program. 

SPSSINC TRANS result = week 
/FORMULA "weekname(day)".
EXECUTE.
```

The warning I get is following:
Warnings
Duplicate variable name.

But the main problem is that there is no values in the Week variable.

Can somebody help here?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I never used `SPSSINC TRANS`, so I don't know how it works. But I doubt it is working like that, since you are passing a text (`"weekname(day)"`) ; I don't think you can call a python function outside a  `begin program / end prorgam` structure. same goes for `day`: that is an SPSS variable, not a python variable. Sorry, can't quite put an actual answer together at the moment, but I hope these will help

Comment: The function call is correct as per IBM support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter version of your solution:

```
STRING  weekname(A11).  
COMPUTE weekname=STRING(datesum(date, -(xdate.wkday(date) - 1), 'days'),DATE11).
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got a solution from IBM support. There is no need to use python here.

```
do if xdate.wkday(date) eq 1.  
compute weekname = date.  
else.  
compute weekname = datesum(date, -(xdate.wkday(date) - 1), 'days').  
end if.  
formats weekname(date11).  

STRING  asastring (A11).  
COMPUTE asastring=STRING(weekname,DATE11).  
EXECUTE.

DELETE VARIABLES weekname.

RENAME VARIABLES asastring=weekname.
```